# Trello email notification

Tags: trello

I'd like to send Evernote reminders from a Card. Is there a way to customize the email template used in notifications (ie: set the subject to something different from 'Trello Notification'), so that Evernote can assign the Card in the appropriate Notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no, Trello doesn't offer customizable emails. We are working on an API, however, which would allow you to integrate with Evernote.